# Problem in wiimote_node.py

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

i have a problem when i start the wiimote_node with rosrun wiimote wiimote_node.py. I get the following error message:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "wiimote_node.py", line 100, in 
import wiimote.WIIMote
File "/opt/ros/electric/stacks/joystick_drivers/wiimote/src/wiimote/WIIMote.py", line 48, in 
import cwiid
ImportError: /opt/ros/electric/stacks/joystick_drivers/cwiid/cwiid/lib/libcwiid.so.1: undefined symbol: clock_gettime

has anyone encountered the problem yet? I'm running out of ideas.

My os is ubuntu 11.10 32-bit

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/28084/problem-in-wiimote_node.py/) by [E.Hauck](https://answers.ros.org/users/1828/e.hauck/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-02-21

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mmwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/2/mmwise/) on 2012-03-16**:
can you include what version of joystick drivers you have installed (look at the CMakeLists.txt in joystick_drivers).. I just installed the latest from the package manager (1.6.4) and ran it and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes I have had the same problem.

It is the libcwiid that comes with ROS Electric that is the problem. You can solve it be doing the following:

install libcwiid1 and libcwiid-dev with synaptic or apt.

go to

/opt/ros/electric/stacks/joystick_drivers/cwiid/cwiid/lib/

remove or rename

libcwiid.so
libcwiid.so.1
libcwiid.so.1.0

Create the following symbolic links with “sudo ln -s”

libcwiid.so -> /usr/lib/libcwiid.so
libcwiid.so.1 -> /usr/lib/libcwiid.so.1
libcwiid.so.1.0 -> /usr/lib/libcwiid.so.1.0

example: sudo ln -s libcwiid.so /usr/lib/libcwiid.so

This will solve your problem.

---

Originally posted by [claeslund](https://answers.ros.org/users/1989/claeslund/) with karma: 36 on 2012-03-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [piyushk](https://answers.ros.org/users/1770/piyushk/) on 2012-05-21**:
Had same issue while using wiimote in ROS Electric. The provided solution solved the problem. Also the symbolic link command should be "sudo ln -s /usr/lib/libcwiid.so libcwiid.so"